# UITableView scroll to element programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have array of 20 elements, and table view that can show only 5 of them. On start of view, I am selecting 1 item, and I want to show that item in table view by selecting it. When I choose one of first 5, selection is visible. When I select  5+ element, I want that element to be visible too by moving content offset. How can I scroll `TableView` to specific element from list inside tableview array? In which function of table view delegate do I do that?

I tried setting content offset, and `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but it is not working correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath: at cellForRow will not work..First you need to reload data of tableview and then you need to call as below after selecting an item..

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedRow inSection:0];

[self.tableView reloadData];

[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
    atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: After I initialised tableView, I called reload data, and scrolled table to desired index. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Put your `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` inside `ViewDidLoad` or `ViewWillAppear` of the `TableViewController`.

Comment: I dont have table view controller. I have 3 table views, inside 1 ViewController.

Comment: OK, so in your ViewController, what event triggers the selection?  Put the scrollToRowAtIndexPath in the code that handles that event.